# How to create a script that gives me every combination possible of a six digit code

Tags: python, performance, combinations

Me and a friend want to create a script that gives us every possible permutation of a six digit code, comprised of 36 alphanumeric characters (0-9, and a-z), in alphabetical order, then be able to see them in a .txt file.

And I want it to use all of the CPU and RAM it can, so that it takes less time to complete the task.

So far, this is the code:

```
import random
charset = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
links = []
file = open("codes.txt", "a")

for g in range(0, 36**6):
    key = ""
    base = ""
    print(str(g))
    for i in range(0, 6):
        char = random.choice(charset)
        key += char
    base += key
    file.write(base + "\n")

file.close()
```

This code *randomly* generates the combinations and immediately writes them in a .txt file, while printing the amount of codes it has already created but, it isn't in alphabetical order (have to do it afterwards), and it takes too long.

How can the code be improved to give the desired outcome?

[Thanks to @R0Best for providing the best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69328673/17002136)

Comment: Note that the output will take 14.2 GiB. Note also that Python is not a great tool for performing brute-force operation as the default implementation (CPython) is an a rather slow *interpreter*. It should be much batter to use a native language like C or C++. Having an SSD also help a bit.

Comment: Have you tried using `itertools.combinations`?

Comment: @ TheChris1215 you haven't mentioned anything about the repetition of the characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way I can think of is using [pypy3](https://www.pypy.org/) with this code:

```py
import functools
import time
from string import digits, ascii_lowercase


@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=128)
def main():
    cl = []
    cs = digits + ascii_lowercase
    for letter in cs:
        cl.append(letter)
    ct = tuple(cl)
    with open("codes.txt", "w") as file:
        for p1 in ct:
            for p2 in ct:
                for p3 in ct:
                    for p4 in ct:
                        for p5 in ct:
                            for p6 in ct:
                                file.write(f"{p1}{p2}{p3}{p4}{p5}{p6}\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    main()
    print(f"Done!\nTook {time.time() - start} seconds!")
```

It writes at around 10-15MB/s. The total file is around 15GB I believe so it would take like 990-1500 seconds to generate. The results are on a VM of unraid with 1 3.4 ghz core of server CPU, with an old SATA3 SSD. You will probably get better results with an NVME drive and a faster single core CPU.

Comment: A few suggestions: you can use cs = .... ;    cl = list(cs); and concatenating strings using `+` is way slower than using f-strings, so it should be `file.write(f"{p1}{p2}{p3}{p4}{p5}{p6}\n")`

Comment: Sorry! didn't quite do the math :/, corected in the answer

Comment: Oh man, wow, you weren't lying when you said it's the fastest way, got it done in about 15 minutes, thank you so much, now I'll continue my journey...

Comment: the ladder of loops could be simplified in a unique one with `itertools.product`

Comment: There's a lot wrong with this answer-  you don't need `lru_cache`- the function is only called once, and never returns anything. You shouldn't `file.write` so many times, that's already introducing more overhead than you save. The appending/casting at the top is entirely unnecessary- just iterate over the string.

Comment: If you don't file.write every  time and you store it in RAM it takes to much space for a 16GB machine and crashes. An actual improvement I found later on is buffering variable in open() but OP doesn't need it anymore as he got the file ready.

Answer (score 3):

Although this post already has 6 answers, I'm not content with any of them, so I've decided to contribute a solution of my own.

First, note that many of the answers provide the `combinations` or `permutations` of letters, however the post actually wants the Cartesian Product of the alphabet with itself (repeated N times, where N=6). There is (at this time) two answers that do this, however they both `write` an excessive number of times, resulting in subpar performance, and also concatenate their intermediate results in the hottest portion of the loop (also bringing down performance).

In the interest of taking optimization to the absolute max, I present the following code:

```py
from string import digits, ascii_lowercase
from itertools import chain

ALPHABET = (digits + ascii_lowercase).encode("ascii")

def fast_brute_force():
    # Define some constants to make the following sections more readable
    base_size = 6
    suffix_size = 4
    prefix_size = base_size - suffix_size
    word_size = base_size + 1
    
    # define two containers
    #   word_blob - placeholder words, with hyphens in the unpopulated characters (followed by newline)
    #   sleds - a tuple of repeated bytes, used for substituting a bunch of characters in a batch
    word_blob = bytearray(b"-" * base_size + b"\n")
    sleds = tuple(bytes([char]) for char in ALPHABET)

    # iteratively extend word_blob and sleds, and filling in unpopulated characters using the sleds
    # in doing so, we construct a single "blob" that contains concatenated suffixes of the desired
    # output with placeholders so we can quickly substitute in the prefix, write, repeat, in batches
    for offset in range(prefix_size, base_size)[::-1]:
        word_blob *= len(ALPHABET)
        word_blob[offset::word_size] = chain.from_iterable(sleds)
        sleds = tuple(sled * len(ALPHABET) for sled in sleds)
    
    with open("output.txt", "wb") as f:
        # I've expanded out the logic for substituting in the prefixes into explicit nested for loops
        # to avoid both redundancy (reassigning the same value) and avoiding overhead associated with
        # a recursive implementation
        # I assert this below, so any changes in suffix_size will fail loudly
        assert prefix_size == 2
        for sled1 in sleds:
            word_blob[0::word_size] = sled1
            for sled2 in sleds:
                word_blob[1::word_size] = sled2
                # we write to the raw FileIO since we know we don't need buffering or other fancy
                # bells and whistles, however in practice it doesn't seem that much faster
                f.raw.write(word_blob)
```

There's a lot of magic happening in that code block, but in a nutshell:

- I batch the writes, so that I'm writing `36**4` or `1679616` entries at once, so there's less context switching.
- I update all `1679616` entries per batch simultaneously with the new prefix, using bytearray slicing / assignment.
- I operate on bytes, write to the raw FileIO, expand the loops for the prefix assignments, and other small optimizations to avoid encoding/buffering/function call overhead/other performance hits.

Note, unless you have a *very* fast disk and slowish CPU, you won't see much benefit from the smaller optimizations, just the write batching probably.

On my system, it takes about 45 seconds to product + write the `14880348` file, and that's writing to my slowest disk. On my NVMe drive, it takes `6.868` seconds.

Answer (score 0):

First thing; There is better ways to do this but I want to write something clear and understandable.

Pseudo Code:

```
base = "";
for(x1=0; x1<charset.length(); x1++)
    for(x2=0; x2<charset.length(); x2++)
        for(x3=0; x3<charset.length(); x3++)
            .
            .
            .
        { base = charset[x1]+charset[x2]+charset[x3]+.....+charset[x6];
          file.write(base + "\n")
        }
```

Comment: So in this case, I need to write the "for(x1=0", "x1++)", and "charset[x1]" and keep replacing the number 1 until I get to "for(x36=0", "x36++)", and "charset[x36]", yeah?

Comment: @TheChris1215 sorry it was a mistake, you only needs 6 digits so you will go until you reach X6 only, I've fixed my answer

Answer (score 0):

For permutations, this would do the trick:

```
from itertools import permutations
charset = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
links = []
with open("codes.txt", "w") as f:
    for permutation in permutations(charset, 6):
        f.write(''.join(permutation) + '\n')
```

FYI, it would create a 7.8 GigaByte file

For combinations, this would do the trick:

```
from itertools import combinations
charset = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
links = []
with open("codes.txt", "w") as f:
    for comb in combinations(charset, 6):
        f.write(''.join(comb)+ '\n')
```

FYI, it would create a 10.8 megabyte file

Answer (score 0):

Random Can be very inefficient. You can try :

```
from itertools import permutations
from pandas import Series
charset = list("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
links = []
file = open("codes.txt", "a")
comb = permutations(charset,6)
comb = list(comb)
comb = list(map(lambda x:return ''.join(x),comb))
mySeries = Series(comb)
mySeries = mySeries.sort_values()

base = ""
for k in mySeries:
    base += k
file.write(base + "\n")

file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itertools.permutaions` from the default `itertools` library. You can also specify the number of characters in the combination.

```
from itertools import permutations
charset = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

c = permutations(charset, 6)

with open('code.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in c:
        f.write("".join(i) + '\n')
```

Runs on my computer in about 200 milliseconds for creating the list of permutations, then spends a lot of time writing to the file

Answer (score 0):

This is a combination problem where you are trying to get combinations of length 6 from the character set of length 36. This will produce an output of size 36!/(30!*6!) . You can refer the itertools for solving a combination problem like yours. You can refer the Combination function in itertools
[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). It is recommended not to perform such a performance intensive computation using Python.

Comment: Yeah I didn't consider that seems like OP want to have repetition of characters as well. It will even worsen the performance.